# Send the value of a Javascript variable into a Go variable

Tags: javascript, go

I need to read the value of a Javascript variable (`JS2GO`) in my Go code (`v.Hostname`). I do not know how to do it.

I have read a bit about `syscall/js` but I could not find anything.

It is the Javascript code:

```
    $(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
          var JS2GO = $(this).val();
      }
    });
```

And here is the form I have in my `.gohtml` file.

```html
    <form method="POST">
      <input id="myInput" type="text" name="host">
      <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" tabindex="-1">
    </form>
```

P.S.

I came up with this solution because I can't click on "submit" button (it is hidden), then it doesn't send the results to my Go code. It means that I cannot read the value of `input` by this code: `v.Host = r.FormValue("host")`. Please let me know if my approach is not optimal.

Comment: If you can't send the variable's value over the network, whatever the reason, your Go code will not be able to know what the js value is.

Comment: make an ajax query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment of @G.aziz, I have found a solution mentioned [here](https://socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-jquery-ajax-post-data-to-server-and-send-data-back-to-client-example). In my case, it got fixed in this way:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="host" style="min-width: 220px;" placeholder="Hostname; e.g. crowe.org">
    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" tabindex="-1">
</form>
```

and the Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'HTML',
          data : {
            ajax_post_data: $('#myInput').val()
          },
        });
     });
});
```

Then in my Go file, I can get the value like this

```
if r.Method == "POST" {
    v.Host = r.FormValue("ajax_post_data")
}
```